Create iOS distribution certificate not possible via Visual Studio
I would like to publish my first iOS app in the AppStore.
Unfortunately I'm stuck at the following point in Visual Studio (Windows):
When I click Options -> Xamarin -> Apple Accounts -> MY_ACCOUNT -> MY_TEAM -> Details -> "Create Certificate" I cannot click "iOS-distribution". iOS-distribution is grayed out. iOS development is clickable.
Checklist:

I am registered in the Apple Developer Program.
I logged in to appstoreconnect.apple.com and filled out all the forms (taxes...).
I created an App Store Connect API key with administrator access under appstoreconnect. I have successfully stored this key in Visual Studio. It is displayed and the role is also set to Administrator.Creating iOS-development certificates works without any problems.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
I follow the official instructions from Microsoft - but I just can't get any further at this point.
The permissions of my Apple Account Team in VS are set to Admin. Here are two pictures that show this. Unfortunately in German, since I work with a German VS:
Image 1:

Image 2:

I found out that manually creating an iOS distribution certificate via https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list with a signing request via the MacOS program "Keychain Access" works - just not via Visual Studio.

If an option in the drop-down is greyed out and unselected, it means that you don't have the correct team permissions to create this type of certificate.
I tested creating the App Store Connect API and set the permissions to Admin.
After that, the iOS Distribution Certificate can be created normally in VS, so what you need to make sure is whether your permissions are set to Admin.
In addition, Apple Developer has a maximum limit on the number of certificates created. You can check whether your Distribution Certificates have been created to the maximum number in certificate list. This may cause you to be unable to create distribution certificates normally.

My team is set to admin. I have added two photos to my post again, where you can see that the authorization is set to admin (in German, administrator).
In my Certificate List there is only on certificate. i don´t think i reached a limit because I can still create developer certificates.

Because you can find the created Distribution Certificate in the keychain of Mac, you can try to import the certificate to Windows device.
specifically: right-click the valid distribution certificate in the keychain ->  click export "certificate name" -> set password and save it on mac-> send the file to the windows device -> then click import certificate next to the create certificates button in VS to import the certificate.
For more details, you can refer to copy a certificate from a Mac to a Windows machine.

If you still want to create a Distribution Certificate through VS, you can first check in the Create a New Certificate whether Apple Distribution or iOS Distribution (App Store Connect and Ad Hoc) can be selected normally
